# connection to cygwin sshd auto connection after log in

Tags: ssh, cygwin

I install the sshd service in cygwin successfully, but when I log in to the ssh server, the connection is auto closed.

I tried to execute the `date` command and it didn't output the result.

I also tried the `ssh -vvv` and there is no error...

What's the problem and how can I resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Please include the output of `ssh -vvv`. It might help us help you.

Comment: @janos I tried the -vvv but it didn't show any errors...

Comment: It shows a lot of stuff. Even if you don't see errors, somebody here might see something interesting. Please also include the exact command line you're executing, for example is it simply `ssh localhost date`, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

which user do you use?

If you use the default `cyg_server` user, then check the `/etc/passwd` file to check the user's login shell.

Check if the login shell is exist.

If everything is ok, then show your `ssh -vvv` result :-)

Comment: I see, the user is created when I execute the `ssh-host-config`, so it's login shell is `/bin/false`, I change it to `/bin/bash`, then I can log in now, Thanks.